# htaccess redirectmatch regular expression to avoid infinite loop

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a malformed link somewhere which sends people to my sitemap but to a URL like

```
www.example.com/sitemap.php'"abc def
```

etc. This then presents them with broken links.

While I hunt down the bad link, I wrote a 301 like this to make all traffic to the page be 301ed and cleaned up:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^sitemap.php(.*) http://www.example.com/sitemap.php
```

But this gives me a "too many 301s" errors because site.com/sitemap.php matches the expression and it gets looped. Is there a regular expression that I can use instead of (.*) that will not match if there is nothing there at all (ie if the URL just ends with ".php"?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(sitemap\.php).+ /$1
```

And clear your browser cache. Note use of `.+` (1 or more of any character) instead of `.*` (0 or more chars)